# Python - HTML/JQUERY Pagination

Tags: javascript, python, html, jquery, django

Hello friends and colleagues in the community, I am trying to make a pagination bar, the problem is that using a button I can only print/function the first page but not the remaining pages.

[Pagination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCS4j.png)

This is my code:

```
<div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {    
        $("#descargar").DataTable({                             
            "lengthChange": true,
            "searching": true,
            "ordering": true,
            "info": true, 
            "autoWidth": false,
            "responsive": true,                                                        
            language: {
                "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
                "zeroRecords": "No se encontraron resultados",
                "info": "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
                "infoEmpty": "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
                "infoFiltered": "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
                "sSearch": "Buscar:",
                "oPaginate": {
                    "sFirst": "Primero",
                    "sLast":"Último",
                    "sNext":"Siguiente",
                    "sPrevious": "Anterior"
                },
                "sProcessing":"Procesando...",
            },      
        }) 
        
        $("#descargar").ready(function() {                        
            $('.fa-binoculars').on('click', function() {                                
                var codigoPartner = $(this).data('codigo-partner');
                                           
                var url_seguimiento = "/seguimiento/" + codigoPartner;                            
                
                window.location.href = url_seguimiento;
            });
        });
    });
</script>
</div>
```

I think the problem could lie in the DataTable but I'm not sure. I would greatly appreciate your help.

What I hope is that the button works on the other pages (pagination)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [drawCallback](https://datatables.net/reference/option/drawCallback) which is called on every draw event of the table.

```
<div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {    
    $("#descargar").DataTable({                             
        "lengthChange": true,
        "searching": true,
        "ordering": true,
        "info": true, 
        "autoWidth": false,
        "responsive": true,
        "drawCallback": function( settings ) {
            $('.fa-binoculars').on('click', function() {                                
                var codigoPartner = $(this).data('codigo-partner');
                                       
                var url_seguimiento = "/seguimiento/" + codigoPartner;                            
            
                window.location.href = url_seguimiento;
            });
        });                                            
        language: {
            "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
            "zeroRecords": "No se encontraron resultados",
            "info": "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
            "infoEmpty": "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
            "infoFiltered": "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
            "sSearch": "Buscar:",
            "oPaginate": {
                "sFirst": "Primero",
                "sLast":"Último",
                "sNext":"Siguiente",
                "sPrevious": "Anterior"
            },
            "sProcessing":"Procesando...",
        },      
    });
});
```